# combining or piping two sed commands with different parameters

Tags: bash, sed

I have an xml file (not a valid xml though) containing lines:

```
 <seg id="65"> Kostenvoranschlag der Werkstatt in vier Schritten</seg>
```

And I want to replace each line with the content of seg tag. So, this is an ideal output:

```
 Kostenvoranschlag der Werkstatt in vier Schritten
```

Now this works fine in collecting these lines:

```
sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*>\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' file.txt &>log
```

But collects the extra space between *"65">*  and *"Kostenvoranschlag"*. To get rid off that space I can call the following separately:

```
sed -i 's/^ *//' log
```

But I want to do it in one line using piping. I tried a few things but none of them worked:

```
sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*>\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p; -i s/^ *//' file.txt &>log
sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*>\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' file.txt ; -i 's/^ *//' &>log
```

The piping doesn't work since -i is not a command:

```
sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*>\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' file.txt | -i 's/^ *//' &>log
```

Any comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this `*` after the `<seg id=.*>` part of your regex:

```
sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*> *\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' file
                       ^^
```

This matches any amount of spaces (zero to n) after `<seg id=XXXX>`.

Test:

```
$ sed -n 's:.*<seg id=.*> *\(.*\)</seg>.*:\1:p' <<< " <seg id="65"> Kostenvoranschlag der Werkstatt in vier Schritten</seg>"
Kostenvoranschlag der Werkstatt in vier Schritten
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input file is a valid XML document, use an XML parser with an xpath that matches the parts you're interested in:

```
xmllint --xpath '//seg/text()' file.xml
```

This is much more simple and robust than relying on a regular expression, which will break for many inputs that are otherwise valid such as text nodes containing line breaks, or `<seg>` elements that have other attributes.

Comment: It's not a valid xml file and xmllint fails to parse it properly :)

Comment: Well in that case, I would hesitate to say "I have an XML file" in your question!